# Replacing upper-case with upper-case and lower-case with lower-case

Tags: android, android-layout

I am highlighting the text in textviews after search and replacing with this code..

```
 txtV.setText(Html.fromHtml((text.replaceAll("(?i)" 
    + searchText,"<font color='#53f721'>" + searchText + "</font>")));
```

But all the uppercase characters are get replaced by lowercase.
I want uppercase char to be replaced by uppercase and lowercase char by lowercase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a clear problem statement to your question.  Also, I doubt your description of the current behavior.  Maybe add some sample data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are replacing original text with `searchText`, and by using `(?i)` replace function works case-insensitive.

If I want to do this, I prefer to use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) like bellow:

```
String originalText = "Your original text";
Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(originalText);
originalText = originalText.toLowerCase();
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
int length = searchText.length();
int index = originalText.indexOf(searchText);
while (index >= 0) {
    wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    index = originalText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText, index + length);
}
txtV.setText(wordToSpan);
```

Comment: Thank You @Mir Milad Hosseiny

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression abilities in the following way:

```
txtV.setText(Html.fromHtml((text.replaceAll("(?i)" 
    + searchText,"<font color='#53f721'>$0</font>")));
```